# Decode QR codes from the pdf programmatically without scanning them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, qr-code

I created the pdf that contains multiple QR codes, Now I want to decode all the QR codes which are present in the PDF file without scanning them, I searched about it and didn't get anything.

Thanks in advance

I'm creating the QR codes using `rqrcode` gem.

Comment: I would say: Step 1: extract the images from the PDF

Comment: You can use [pdfimages](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pdfimages) command to extract the images.

Comment: @javiyu what should I do after extracting the images?

Comment: Try using [zbarimg](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/zbarimg.1.html) to extract the text from the image

Comment: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/QR_Codes

Comment: You are asking to re-invent the wheel, and basically have code that interprets a QR code. As QR codes are standardized, the result is the same every time. Others have done the job. I would not spend the time, as QR codes are fairly complex. Unless it's for your own challenge.